# easily integrate socket.io and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, socket.io, faye, private-pub

I am using rails for more than 2 years now,,now I am building a real time application which is simple social network ,using private_pub gem for commenting and notifications ,I read about nodejs and I am learning it for the 3rd week now ,nodejs is really amazing platform ,,but I want to know how I can integrate nodejs and socket.io with my rails app for providing online/offline feature and also for chatting .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check this post, it's a tutorial for integrating Rails + node.js + socket.io + redis

http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/

Comment: Thanks dear moustafa  ya gada3,,actually I integrated socket.io with my rails app after 1 day from asking my question but I forgot to answer it .Its so easy but you need to take care of security .you are using sockets at the end

Comment: el 3afw ya Remon :)
welcome, did you complete the project with Faye server or node.js? 
any information about the scalability of Faye ? as I was planning to use it for sockets.
thanks :)

Comment: thanks ya sa7by ,,actually I am using both faye and socket.io on my current and new rails apps ..socket.io for detecting online/offline users and faye for pub/sub but If you have any articles about fayejs security except on fayejs site ,,,I will be so happy